# OS X 10.7 and 10.8 continuously going corrupt on several machines, disk unable to repair, requires clean install

Tags: macos, mac, ssd, imac, disk-utility

I'm managing about a dozen iMacs varying in age from 3 years to 6 months. Every iMac has an afterparty **256GB Crucial M4 SSD**, which have all been installed since roughly the beginning of the year. These disks are rarely even half full.

Around 4 months ago, one of the computers began slowing down and hanging for minutes at a time. After investigating, Disk Utility confirmed the disk needed repair, but couldn't be repaired. The internet confirmed with certainty that the only to resolve that is to format the disk and restore from backup or start from scratch. To be safe, though, and since one error code indicated a hardware issue with the SSD, I installed a new one. After a fresh install, everything's been fine since on that machine.

Then, a couple months ago, another machine did the same thing. Same result, unable to repair disk. This time, I kept the disk in and did a clean install of the OS. No more verify disk issues, and it's also been fine since.

Now, two more machines are having trouble. One is gradually slowing down and has issues verifying the disk and can't repair, the other, my machine, is behaving much more strangely. A month ago, I woke the computer form sleep one morning, and 3-4 applications had to be force quit. Then they wouldn't re-open, crashing immediately. Chrome (stable) crashed the instant you tried to upload a file, Rdio wouldn't open at all, same for iChat. After a restart, the issues persisted, and after another restart the machine would no longer boot. It shuts off at the gray Apple logo screen, after the chime.

I formatted and re-installed. Again, fine since, but on Thursday, similar symptoms in the same order with the same timing - on the third restart, the system refuses to boot.

Now, I haven't done anything with these last two machines yet. Is there a specific log file that might be helpful in diagnosing this? After four machines, I'm baffled as to what the issue is. Three of the machines that had problems are on 10.7, mine is on 10.8. All up to date. No signs of malware or viruses on the network. Pretty typical applications - Creative Suite, text editors, messaging clients.

The issue is not backups or restoring data, we have our bases covered there. It's figuring out why our machines keep caving in on themselves.

Please let me know how I can provide more information - one machine having problems boots and works (just slowly), the other won't boot at all past the gray Apple screen. Both have disk verification issues.

Thank you in advance!